# MS Access Select Statement with Top X Distinct with Order By

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I'm trying to write a MS Access query that will return the top X distinct production orders as ordered by SummaryEntryNumber descending, but when trying to use distinct or group by the data is being returned out of order.

Table: tblSummary

```
SummaryEntryNumber | ProductionOrder
2720               | 81184419
2719               | 81184419
2718               | 81184418
2717               | 81184418
2716               | 81184418
2715               | 81184418
2714               | 81184418
2713               | 81184416
2712               | 81170839
2711               | 81170839
2710               | 81170839
2709               | 81170839
2708               | 81170665
2707               | 81170665

 SELECT TOP 3 ProductionOrder FROM
 (
        SELECT SummaryEntryNumber, ProductionOrder
        FROM tblSummary
        ORDER BY SummaryEntryNumber DESC
 )
```

Returns: Order is correct, but contains duplicates:

```
ProductionOrder
81184419
81184419
81184418
```

```
 SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 ProductionOrder FROM
 (
        SELECT SummaryEntryNumber, ProductionOrder
        FROM tblSummary
        ORDER BY SummaryEntryNumber DESC
 )
```

Returns: No duplicates, but order is not correct

```
ProductionOrder
81147954
81149278
81149279
```

I'm expecting it the query to return:

```
ProductionOrder
81184419
81184418
81184416
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following should suffice:

```
select top 3 t.productionorder
from tblsummary t
group by t.productionorder
order by max(t.summaryentrynumber) desc
```

Here, each distinct `productionorder` value is ordered by the maximum `summaryentrynumber` within each group of `summaryentrynumber` values for a given `productionorder` value, producing the desired result -

```
productionorder
81184419
81184418
81184416
```

Comment: That did it!  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

First `group by ProductionOrder` to get the maximum `SummaryEntryNumber` for each `ProductionOrder` and then sort the result and get `TOP 3`:

```
SELECT TOP 3 t.ProductionOrder
FROM (
  SELECT ProductionOrder, MAX(SummaryEntryNumber) AS MaxSummaryEntryNumber
  FROM tblSummary 
  GROUP BY ProductionOrder
) AS t
ORDER BY t.MaxSummaryEntryNumber DESC
```

Results:

```
ProductionOrder
81184419
81184418
81184416
```

Comment: This one also works.  Thank for taking the time to look at this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an explicit ORDER BY clause for ProductionOrder also

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 ProductionOrder
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT SummaryEntryNumber, ProductionOrder
      FROM tblSummary
      ORDER BY SummaryEntryNumber DESC, ProductionOrder DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit tricky, but you should also use the DISTINCT clause in the subquery for it to work as expected:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 ProductionOrder FROM
 (
        SELECT DISTINCT SummaryEntryNumber, ProductionOrder
        FROM tblSummary
        ORDER BY SummaryEntryNumber DESC
 )
```

This works fine.